# AFIncrementalStore and AFNetworking 2.0

Tags: ios, afnetworking, afnetworking-2, afincrementalstore

AFIncrementalStore seems to have a dependency on AFHTTPClient which is no longer available in AFNetworking 2.0? Is there an updated version of AFIncrementalStore for AFNetworking 2.0, or am I just missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not missing anything, unfortunately there is no updated version of AFIncrementalStore for AFNetworking 2.0. It seems that AFIncrementalStore is not actively maintained at the moment.

There are a couple of issues, [#242](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFIncrementalStore/pull/242) and [#248](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFIncrementalStore/pull/248), where some support has been provided by third parties.

Comment: Yep, I saw those and grabbed a version, I'm hoping to do my own version. It does seem to be not actively maintained, which leads me to question whether or not it's wise to build my APIClient based on it. Have you used it and had success?

Comment: I actually did try it before AFN 2.0 was release and while it was novel, it didn't really work well enough for my needs. I wrote my own code to use `AFHttpRequestOperationManager` and [Mantle](https://github.com/MantleFramework/Mantle) to create `NSManagedObject`s and saved them to the persistent store myself.

Comment: Thanks for the insight. It seems to me like managing the interaction between CoreData and a web service API is way more complicated than it needs to be. I'm surprised this issue hasn't been addressed by Apple at all. I would definitely be interested in working on an open source solution.

Comment: I think it's too application specific for Apple to bridge the two in a flexible way. You need to come up with a strategy for syncing and then write the code to persist data from your web service.